Do equity futures contracts bleed money?
According to the spot-futures parity:
$$ F = S\exp^{rt}$$
where $F$ is the futures price, $S$ is the spot price, $r$ is the interest rate, and $t$ is the maturity. Dividends are assumed to be zero.
My question is, does the buyer of this contract not lose money on average, all else equal?
At time $t$, our best guess of the stock's worth is $S$ (due to the efficient market hypothesis).
So at time $t$, I will be  paying $F$ and receiving $S$. So my profit is $$S - F = (1 - \exp^{rt})$$
So if $r > 0$, my profits are negative. And I am thus losing money?

The efficient market hypothesis does not propose that stock prices are expected to stay constant.

It also does not propose that they rise. That's the whole point. We don't know what the stock is going to do, so our best guess is that $S_t = S_0$.
Think of it not like a stock index, but a random stock. Tesla, or whatever. Then if you buy a future on a Tesla stock, and $r > 0$, you are bleeding money, according to my calculations.

The forward price of the stock is $Se^{rt}$.  That’s presumably a better guess than $S$

It's just basic cost of carry logic.

When you enter into the futures contract, you don't have to pay any money (other than a small deposit). Somone else will use their own money to buy the basket of stocks now and will deliver them to you at the maturity date at an agreed price. In return for this service they expect to be earn the risk free rate $r$ on their money. Which seems fair to both parties. The r represents a financing cost, it is not money thrown out the window, it allows you to defer payment ,

@dm63 No, it's not. Rates and stocks can correlate but in principal have nothing to do with each other. The $r$ only shows up in the forward price since its a financing cost for the counter-party, it is NOT an indicator of future stock values.

@nbbo2 you agree with me that dm63 (who has more reputation than you) is wrong right?

No, dm63 is always right ;) There is some return on capital in this world, whether it is stocks bonds or anything else. A dollar today does not equal a dollar tomorrow.

Maybe an easier way to explain it, leaning in @AKdemy s point. If I buy cash and sell fut, I will carry negatively to expiry - but I have a mtm gain as the fut and spot must converge. My pnl would be 0, were I to hold this to expiry.

@user68819 why are you talking about the seller? I'm talking about the buyer. Yes of course the seller has zero pnl. but the buyer bleeds money, as I just argued in my post.

@nbbo2 Yes of course S tomorrow is not worth S today, but S, in nominal terms, is the same number tomorrow as it is today.

We are running out of ideas to explain to you how a futures contract works. They are more than 300 years old. Therefore I am sure that you can find plenty of sources to study them.


At time t, our best guess of the stock's worth is S

No, at time t the best guess of the stock whose current price is $S$ is $Se^{rt}$ due to the time value of money.
If your best guess on the future price of the stock was S, then instead of buying for S now, one would enter into a contract to buy the stock for S in the future, invest the funds at rate r, and wait, making an arbitrage profit.  Therefore forward stock prices always are a future value based on a risk-free interest rate.
(There may be other ways to explain it to be more precise, but the market certainly prices stock futures with this principle)
It's not saying that the stock is guaranteed to be the future price, just used to prevent arbitrage scenarios.
